# Javascript code doesn't work in IE only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have just verified my javascript code works fine in all browsers except IE. How is it possible that the script is correctly read and executed in Chrome, Safari... but IE finds some inexplicable error and refuses to run the code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var NewsNavigator = {

            init: function(config) {
                this.news = config.news;
                this.newsNum = this.news.length;
                this.navbuttons = config.navbuttons;
                this.prevButton = config.prevButton;
                this.nextButton = config.nextButton;
                this.displayatonce = config.displayatonce;
                this.maxSteps = Math.ceil(this.newsNum / this.displayatonce);
                this.counter = 0;
                this.navigateNews();
                this.enableNav();
                this.checkButtonsVisibility();

            },

            showNews: function() {
                var start = this.counter * this.displayatonce;
                var end = this.counter * this.displayatonce + (this.displayatonce - 1);
                for (i=start; i<=end; i++) {
                    this.news.eq(i).show();
                }

            },

            hideAllNews: function() {
                console.log("hiding news");
                this.news.hide();
            },

            navigateNews: function() {
                this.hideAllNews();
                this.showNews();
            },

            checkButtonsVisibility: function() {
                if (this.counter <= 0)
                {
                    this.prevButton.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }
                else
                {
                    this.prevButton.css('visibility', 'visible');
                }

                if (this.counter >= this.maxSteps - 1) 
                {
                    this.nextButton.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }
                else
                {
                    this.nextButton.css('visibility', 'visible');
                }
            },

            enableNav: function() {
                self = this;
                this.navbuttons.on('click', function(event) {
                    if (($(this).data('dir') === 'prev') && (self.counter > 0)) {
                        self.counter--;
                        self.navigateNews();
                    } else if (($(this).data('dir') === 'next') && (self.counter < self.maxSteps - 1)) {
                        self.counter++;
                        self.navigateNews();
                    }
                self.checkButtonsVisibility();
                event.preventDefault(); 
                });
            }
        };

        NewsNavigator.init({
            news: $('div#cat-news').find('div.oneCol'),
            displayatonce: 3,
            navbuttons: $('div#nav').find('a'),
            prevButton: $('div#nav a.prec'),
            nextButton: $('div#nav a.succ')
        });
});
```

Error message in IE9

```
SCRIPT438: The object doesn't support the 'checkButtonsVisibility' property or method.
NewsNavigator.js, Row 69 Character 5
```

Comment: We can't help without seeing your javascript.

Comment: @haunted85 All browsers have their own subtle differences in the way JavaScript interacts with documents, as well as how much of ECMAScript (and which version) is implemented. You'll need to show us your code for further help.

Comment: Also make sure you don't have any object literals with commas right before a closing `}`

Comment: It is more then possible, I'd say its a typical situation :) as of ie 7 you have a developer console, where you can see which line of code fails. E.g. For me the IndexOf method failed for strings in IE, so I had to extend the string object in my code for it to work. You may find similar solution.

Comment: Inexplicable errors are usually only inexplicable so long as they are kept secret from people who might explain them.

Comment: @haunted85 Thank you for posting your code; now can you share any console output you might be seeing in IE, and perhaps the version of IE you're testing against?

Answer (score 3):

Well this comes down to the history of JavaScript.

JavaScript was implemented based on ECMAScript:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript

Each and every single Web Browser provider (Mozilla, Google, Microsoft) decided that they didn't want to standardize JavaScript and they each came up with their own implementation of the ECMAScript, and thus their own JavaScript engine.

Thus, we programmers get a headache trying to write JavaScript that is compatible across all these different JavaScript engines because each of them read JavaScript in their own way (which answers your question of why IE finds some inexplicable error while the rest doesn't)

Fun Fact: Only Mozilla's implementation of ECMAScript is actually called "JavaScript".

You should lookup on how to write JavaScript that is cross-compatible across different JavaScript engines.

Comment: Actually if we're being pedantic ECMAScript was based on Netscape's original JavaScript; that is, JavaScript was released to the public before work on the specification was even begun.

Comment: The problems have very little to do with the difference between JScript and JavaScript. Most of them come down to differences with the DOM APIs and browsers that haven't implemented features in the newer versions of JavaScript (1.6 and later).

Answer (score 2):

Use a javascript validation tool, such as [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to ensure maximum compability. This, since a single omitted character (such as `;`, `'`, etc) can cause your script to not be run in specific browsers.

JSLint will also provide different tips on what do to and not to do to provide even further compability.

Comment: JSLint won't ensure maximum compatibility. Some things are just fundamentally  different, especially regarding event handling, such as `attachEvent`/`addEventListener` or `event.srcElement`/`event.target`

Comment: @FelixKling while you're absolutely right - it sure does enhance compability at least, even though it doesn't ensure that it will work on all browsers. If you disagree with my answer, feel free to edit it (especially since English isn't my native language - my words might be a bit inappropriate sometimes), or vote it down.